# Auth Token missing while integrating swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to do swagger Integration in my application. So for that I have added this in build.gradle.

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9'
```

This is in MyApplication.java

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = “Backend API", version = "2.0", description = "Backend Details"),
        servers = {@Server(url= "https://"+"${server.DNSName}"+"${server.servlet.contextPath}")}
)
@SecurityScheme(name = "Authorization", scheme = "bearer", type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY, in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER)
```

Now when I am accusing this api  : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I am getting

**{"timeStamp":null,"error":"AUTH TOKEN MISSING","code":null,"fieldErrors":null,"objectErrors":null}**

This the place where I am getting error

```
@Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws AuthenticationException {
    Authentication auth = null;
    User user = null;
    Object uuid = request.getSession().getAttribute("uuid");
    if (uuid != null) {
      try {
        user = userService.findByAuthenticityToken(uuid.toString());
        user.setAuthType(AuthenticationType.valueOf(request.getSession().getAttribute("authenticationType").toString()));
        log.info("Retrieved User From Session --> " + user);
        CurrentUserContext.setCurrentUser(user);
        auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
      } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      }
    } else {
      log.info("No User Found with uuid");
    }

    if (isSessionRequest(request) && auth == null) {
      auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null);
    }
    if (auth == null) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("AUTH TOKEN MISSING");
    }
    return auth;
  }
```

This is what I have given in application.yml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui-custom.html
```

I am using Spring 2.7.1 which I need to migrate to Spring 3.0 in later.

Comment: pls provide all log about the question

Comment: base on the information you provided now, the most possible reason is a  `uuid == null` request.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori yes.uuid is going null and that is causing `BadCredentialsException `  what i am seeking help is what shall I change in swagger integration part.

Comment: pls add your swagger config file, such as `swagger-config.yaml`

Comment: `swagger-config.yml` not need as per the doc. I have updated the question with the change in `application.yml`

Comment: pls check if all field in `request` are null, or just `uuid` is null. If all field in `request` are null, I think you may need to start with swagger hello world project and get a first non-null request.